# why Exception Constructor is called instead of IOException Constructor?

Tags: java, overloading

Below is a java class, named *AuthentificationResourceException*, which extends *Exception* and having 2 overloaded constructors.
For simplicity, this exception will be thrown when the user call verifyToken method situated in a Controller class.

```
 public class AuthentificationResourceException extends Exception{

    // Exception constructor
    public AuthentificationResourceException(Exception cause, VerifyTokenResponse response) {
            handleException(response, "Exception verifyToken method");
        }

    // IOException constructor
    public AuthentificationResourceException(IOException cause, VerifyTokenResponse response) {
        handleException(response, "Probleme of reading / writting");
    }

    public void handleException(VerifyTokenResponse response, String messageException) {
        response.setValid(false);
        response.setCause(messageException);
    }
```

In the controller class, I used @ExceptionHandler annotation to manage unhandled exceptions thrown by verifyToken method :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/authentification", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json"){
public class AuthentificationRessource {



            @RequestMapping(value = "/verifyToken", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
            @ExceptionHandler({ AuthentificationResourceException.class })
            @ResponseBody
            public VerifyTokenResponse verifyToken(@RequestBody VerifyTokenRequest request)
                    throws AuthentificationResourceException {

                JWTVerifier verifier = new JWTVerifier("TOTO");
                VerifyTokenResponse response = new VerifyTokenResponse();

                try {
                    Map<String, Object> mapper = verifier.verify(request.getToken());
                    response.setMapper(mapper);
                    response.setValid(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // map exceptions with ExceptionHandler
                    throw new AuthentificationResourceException(e, response);
                }
                return response;
            }

}
```

When I used, Junit to test verifyToken method, I encounter a problem :

1. When the exception is null and of type **IOException**, the system invoke the second constructor  *IOException constructor*
2. When the exception is not null and instance of **IOException**, the system invoke the first constructor **Exception constructor** instead of **IOException constructor**.

What is the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, overloaded methods are are resolved at compile time.  So in the catch clause, the function can be any exception according to its compile-time type, therefore java resolved the function call to the first constructor.

The null case is interesting.  That's just java resolving to the most specific constructor when it can't determine the objects input type.

One way to solve this would be a runtime type check.

```
  public AuthentificationResourceException(Exception cause, VerifyTokenResponse response) {
      if (cause instanceof IOException) {
         handleException(response, "Problem reading / writing");
      } else {
         handleException(response, "Exception verifyToken method");
      }
  }
```

Another option would be to explicitly catch the IOException separately so java will know what method to call.

```
try {
   ...
} catch(IOException e) {
   throw new AuthentificationResourceException(e, response);
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new AuthentificationResourceException(e, response);
}
```

It was an interesting idea to try and overload there but unfortunately the java type system doesn't allow runtime overloading.

Comment: I used the class AuthentificationResourceException, to avoid multiple try/catch block in the code, so I disagree with the second option. For the first option, consider you're many types of exceptions to handle, in that case, you will have many if/else in your code

Comment: You can try and coerce it into a switch statement but it's going to be difficult because you can't switch on class.  Unfortunately, what you are asking for is runtime branching and you are going to need to have branch statements somewhere.

Comment: @Amine: this overload doesn't buy you anything, just file this as a learning experience and try something else.